# Videos on homepage using JS will this effect SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript, video

My website has videos on the homepage that open up in JavaScript without navigating to another page. Many other websites host videos on separate pages, will this effect my SEO?

Comment: Why do you think it would be affected by this?

Comment: Well because they are not being indexed as a separate pages with a title in the URL. They have only a title and an image, once you click it, video will appear. But if user types in the google search one of the titles which are in the page how does google found it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What affects SEO is the actual amount and quality of text that is on your page, not videos. If you're trying to rank for SEO, don't make a page that consists solely of a video with only one line of text.

Remember, the google crawler extracts paragraphs of text from the HTML it picks up on your website then uses that as a factor to determine where in search results your webpage appears.

I'm predicting it will take a long while as well as added expenses on google's end before they will go into scanning video content frame-by-frame to determine website content.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it depends on what you had to begin with. Like Mike said, your primary SEO ranking factors will come from your actual on-page content.

However, if your videos were marked up using structured data, they may have added some SEO value. Even if they were marked up and suddenly became enveloped in JS, it wouldn't play a big enough role to shake up your SEO rankings (unless you had a large amount, and your home page was primarily videos - in which case you wouldn't have much SEO value anyway).

My advice is not to worry about them being in JS. If you want to sustain/increase any SEO value in those videos, host them on YouTube and do some optimization there to increase their visibility. That could help you get some referral traffic or awareness.

Comment: Well my video content is for adult public, so youtube will not work, but I believe I will have rebuild my page because it wont work as I have it right now. Thanks for your thoughts